# Groovy Grails Tool Suite too small heap size, but only on Debug

Tags: java, grails, groovy

When running Groovy Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) version 3.6.4 (latest as of June 2015), on Windows 7 Home 64bit, I get a "Error occurred during initialization of VM Too small initial heap for new size specified".  I have a JAVA_OPTS System Environment variable of "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"  I also have that same value inside the GGTS Menu: Run => Debug Configurations... Arguments Tab, VM arguments. This error does not happen when I do a run-app inside GGTS, and the app successfully starts.  But, when I do try to run using Debug, with the run-app Debug Configuration, I do get this error.  Where else could I possibly set the heap values to make this work in Debug? Any ideas of what else to test, fix, or set to fix this issue?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Most of the GGTS.ini file for the GGTS.exe 
...
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.springsource.ggts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize=512m
-vmargs
-Dgrails.console.enable.interactive=false
-Dgrails.console.enable.terminal=false
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
-Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001

Answer (score 1):

Could not get GGTS to launch my app, no matter what changes I made to -Xms and -Xmx everywhere I could find to make the change. Kept getting the same error. Finally, I stumbled upon this method of setting up the debug. Step 1, start the app from the console (not within GGTS):

```
grails -debug run-app
```

Step 2, in GGTS follow these directions to hook-up to the "grails -debug run-app" you just started (use port 5005 - as displayed in the console window), and when done, click the Debug button at the bottom: [Create a Remote Java Application launch](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-remotejava_launch_config.htm)

Now, debug launches and I can set and view breakpoints inside GGTS.